# how to store the selected value of a spinner in sqlite database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, spinner

i want to store the selected value of a spinner in sqlite database
i am giving spinner value through array adapter
following is my code for spinner

```
ArrayList<String> incorparray = new ArrayList<String>();
incorparray = new ArrayList<String>();
    incorparray.add("DOB");
    incorparray.add("Incorporation Date");
    incorparray.add("Establishment Date");
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, incorparray);

            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    incorporation.setAdapter(adapter);
```

please help! i need it urgently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i want to store the selected value of a spinner in sqlite database

So first you need to set `OnItemSelectedListener()` for your Spinner to be able to handle select events. Then simply on onItemSelected() method just perform insertion ino SQLite with proper method.

**Example:**

```
yousSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long id) {
      String selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
      // make insertion into database
   }

   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

   }
});
```

where **parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()** returns selected item from Spinner.

Comment: i m storing the values using shared prefrences..for example...my editext value is being stored as..`prefEditor.putString("Dirstict", Dirstict);ArrayList<String> dbvalues = new ArrayList<String>();
   dbvalues.add(settings.getString("Dirstict", ""));WayDataBase way = new WayDataBase(ProfilePage2.this);
   way.insertPeopleValues(dbvalues);`

Comment: @user2210351 so what you want? your question is how to store the selected value of a spinner, this is code how to get selected item. if you want to store into SQLite use sqlite, if SharedPeferences, use SharedPreferences.

Comment: But in question u are  saying storing value in DB?

Comment: @user2210351 you want to fill up spinner with data from sqlite?

Comment: `incorporation.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
   
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
    String incorpvalue= adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    
   }
   
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

             }
    
  });` i used this...now can i write  `incorpvalue.setText(settings.getString("Incorporation","")`;

Comment: @user2210351 and where is problem so?

Comment: @Sajmon have a look at my code and c if u can help me [link]pastebin.com/UKgc3KpF

Comment: @Sajmon now can u view it??

Comment: @user2210351 so where is problem? you want to store seleceted item from Spinner to database so where is code for inserting into db?

Comment: @Sajmon thanks for guiding..i finally found the problem! thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Add set on selected listener on spinner and then the selected value is stored in item. Now store the value of item in sqlite using insert query.

```
   spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {


public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
    // ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(0x00000000);



    }

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

});
```